# Why are my uiswitch's getting confused

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiswitch

I have 4 ui switches on one view controller and two are working perfect however the last two  have setup so you can only click on either group or two player however when you click on two player on then click save and go back in it turns both switches on however if you do the same in group it dosnt not do this?

Anyone see what im doing wrong here?

```
   -(void)stateSwitched:(id)sender {
    UISwitch *tswitch = (UISwitch *)sender;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject: tswitch.isOn ? @"YES" : @"NO" forKey:@"truthonoff"];

    [defaults synchronize];
}

-(void)stateSwitcheddare:(id)sender {
    UISwitch *tswitch = (UISwitch *)sender;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setBool: tswitch.isOn forKey:@"groupswitch"];
    [defaults setBool: tswitch.isOn forKey:@"twoplayerswitch"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

-(void)stateSwitchedtwoplayer:(id)sender {
    UISwitch *tswitch = (UISwitch *)sender;
    //turns two player off when on and soforth

    self.groupswitch.on =! tswitch.isOn;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setBool: tswitch.isOn forKey:@"twoplayerswitch"];
    [defaults setBool: !tswitch.isOn forKey:@"groupswitch"];

    [defaults synchronize];
}

-(void)stateSwitchedgroup:(id)sender {
    UISwitch *tswitch = (UISwitch *)sender;
    //turns two player off when on and soforth
    self.twoplayerswitch.on =! tswitch.isOn;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setBool: tswitch.isOn forKey:@"groupswitch"];
    [defaults setBool: tswitch.isOn forKey:@"twoplayerswitch"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

just realised im running this on viewdidload which may be affecting it?

```
[self.twoplayerswitch setOn:[[defaults objectForKey:@"twoplayerswitch"] boolValue] animated:YES];

[self.twoplayerswitch addTarget:self action:@selector(stateSwitchedtwoplayer:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[self.groupswitch setOn:[[defaults objectForKey:@"groupswitch"] boolValue] animated:YES];

[self.groupswitch addTarget:self action:@selector(stateSwitchedgroup:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Comment: look on my previous answer, i forgot to change defaults at first. If you change for example twoplayerswitch, you need to update defaults too

Comment: sorry I'm confussed now can you explain more?

Comment: i changed to following code however still getting error

Comment: doh, there is "!" missing in stateSwitchedgroup, you need to change this line  [defaults setBool: tswitch.isOn forKey:@"twoplayerswitch"]; and change it on [defaults setBool: !tswitch.isOn forKey:@"twoplayerswitch"];

Comment: ok now they both set to off when i reopen it ?

Comment: scratching my head now. hmm

Comment: also i think its got somthing todo with this [self.twoplayerswitch setOn:[[defaults objectForKey:@"twoplayerswitch"] boolValue] animated:YES];
    
    [self.twoplayerswitch addTarget:self action:@selector(stateSwitchedtwoplayer:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    
    [self.groupswitch setOn:[[defaults objectForKey:@"groupswitch"] boolValue] animated:YES];
    
    [self.groupswitch addTarget:self action:@selector(stateSwitchedgroup:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

Answer (score 1):

In the `stateSwitchedtwoplayer` method, you potentially change the state of `self.groupswitch.on`, but you don't save the change to NSUserDefaults.